# How to parse this JSON from swift 3 facebook graph request

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift3

I am using a graph request to get a json using this code:

```
nextrequest.start({ (response: HTTPURLResponse?, result: Any?) in

                print(result)
})
```

this is the json `result` below and I have no idea how to access the the data inside such as gender, id and name...

```
Optional(FacebookCore.GraphRequestResult<FacebookCore.GraphRequest>.success(FacebookCore.GraphResponse(rawResponse: Optional({
gender = male;
id = 1128614937219535;
name = "Rayan Slim";
picture =     {
    data =         {
        height = 320;
        "is_silhouette" = 0;
        url = "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p320x320/12541113_961418627272501_5451131278168499090_n.jpg?oh=47433bc236ce63ce1c07b92499087f29&oe=586A406A";
        width = 320;
    };
};
}))))
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 5):

After permission has been granted here's the function that works.

```
    if AccessToken.current != nil {
    GraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email"]).start({ (urlResponse, requestResult) in

        switch requestResult {
        case .Success(let response):

            if let responseDictionary = response.dictionaryValue {
                let email = responseDictionary["email"] as? String
                print(email)
                let first = responseDictionary["name"] as? String
                print(first)
                if let picture = responseDictionary["picture"] as? NSDictionary {
                    if let data = picture["data"] as? NSDictionary{
                        if let profilePicture = data["url"] as? String {
                            print(profilePicture)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        case .Failed(let error):
            print(error)

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming this method has been deprecated, because as of March 2021, there's no enum for success or failure. It fails with the error "Enum case 'success' not found in type 'Any?'"

Answer (score 3):

This is tested and working in Swift 3, using the Facebook SDK for Swift

```
let pictureRequest = GraphRequest(graphPath: "me/picture?type=large&redirect=false", parameters: [:])
                        pictureRequest.start{
                            (urlResponse, requestResult) in

                            switch requestResult {
                            case .failed(let error):
                                print("error in graph request:", error)
                                break
                            case .success(let graphResponse):
                                if let responseDictionary = graphResponse.dictionaryValue {
                                    print(responseDictionary)

                                    var dict: NSDictionary!

                                    dict = responseDictionary["data"] as! NSDictionary
                                    print(dict)
                                    print(dict["url"])

                                }
                            }

                        }
```

Comment: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3):

```
if let userDataDict = result as? NSDictionary {
    self.first_name = userDataDict["first_name"] as? String
    self.id = userDataDict["id"] as? String
    self.last_name = userDataDict["last_name"] as? String
    let pictDict =  userDataDict["picture"] as? NSDictionary
    let pictureUrl = pictDict?["data"] as? NSDictionary
    self.pictureUrl = pictureUrl?["url"] as? String
}
```

Answer (score 1):

do like

```
 nextrequest.start({ (response: HTTPURLResponse?, result: Any?) in

  print(result)

  if let userData = result as? [NSObject: Any] 
{
     if let name = userData["name"] as? String 
       {

         print(name)
       }
    if let picture = userData["picture"] as? [NSObject: Any] {
                            if let data = picture["data"] as? [NSObject: Any] {
                                if let profilePictureURL = data["url"] as? String {
                                    // Now add the data to the UI elements
                                  print (profilePictureURL)
                                }
                            }
                        }
}

})
```

Comment: these are causing it to fail: Optional(FacebookCore.GraphRequestResult<FacebookCore.GraphRequest>.success(FacebookCore.GraphResponse(rawResponse: Optional({

Answer (score 0):

Make use of some JSON parser, maybe [Unbox](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox) that makes it easier to handle JSON. **This code is not tested**, but it is an outline of how you could do it. It is always code to store data in a struct instead of using dictionaries.

```
typealias JSON = [String: Any]  

protocol Model {
  init?(json: JSON)
}

func getDataFromFacebook() {
  ...
  nextrequest.start { 
    (response: HTTPURLResponse?, result: Any?) in
      self.handleFacebookResult(result)
  }
}

func handleFacebookResult(_ result: Any?) {
  guard 
    let json = result as? JSON,
    let person = Person(json: json)
  else { return }
  //do something with person! :)
}

struct Person: Model {
  let name: String
  let gender: String
  let picture: Picture

  init?(json: JSON) {
    guard
      let name = json["name"] as? String,
      let gender = json["gender"] as? String,
      let pictureJson = json["picture.data"] as? JSON, // "picture.data" possible when using 'Unbox'
      let picture = Picture(json: pictureJson)
    else { return nil }
    self.name = name
    self.gender = gender
    self.picture = picture
  }
}

struct Picture: Model {
  let height: Int // Or maybe float...?
  let width: Int // Or maybe float...?
  let url: String

    init?(json: JSON) {
    guard
      let height = json["height"] as? Int,
      let width = json["width"] as? Int,
      let url = json["url"] as? String
    else { return nil }
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.url
  }
}
```